# how to create an exact copy of plist in documents directory

Tags: iphone, ios, plist

my plist in resource folder is follows:

```
{
    Games = (yz, def, uv);
    Entertainment = (rst, opq, lmn);
    Utilities = (ghi, def, abc);
 }
```

After creating this plist in documents directory, the plist changes to:

```
{
    Entertainment = (rst, opq, lmn); 
    Games = (yz, def, uv); 
    Utilities = (ghi, def, abc);
}
```

ie, plist field become alphabetically sorted.

can you help me to make an exact copy of plist in the documents folder.

Comment: What do you mean by 'make an exact copy of plist in the documents folder'?

Comment: [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:<#(NSString *)#> toPath:<#(NSString *)#> error:<#(NSError **)#>];

Comment: @sunkehappy: exact copy of plist means the order of the fields in both  plist must be same.

Comment: Why do you matter the sequence in the plist file so much? Isn't alphabetically sorted much better than unsorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens beacuse the plist store its values by keys in an order that is unspecified. If fact, if you store some values in the `NSDictionary` sequentially and then log `[dictionary allKeys]`, is not guaranteed that the values ​​will be displayed in the same order in which they were entered in the dictionary, this because they are probably handled as `NSSet` even if `allKeys` is `NSArray`.
So what you could do is to store each values into an `NSArray` in the order that you want,   like:
index 0 -> Games
index 1 -> Entertainment
index 2 -> Utilities